# How to obtain aws account ID from bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, account, aws-sts

So, I would like to obtain my aws account id through a bash script.  I know that when I run `aws sts get-caller-identity`, it returns a json (similar to)

```
{
    "UserId": "JALDKKEABANMFSL:john.doe",
    "Account": "10299301874829",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::10299301874829:assumed-role/admin/john.doe"
}
```

is there a way for my to either just get the "Account" value from the returned json?  I've tried saving the response into a .json file and using jq, but that has been throwing errors.  Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Comment: Yes you can use `jq`, please do add your tried code in your question, thank you.

Comment: Use `--query`, all AWS cli commands support it.

Comment: `aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query Account`

Answer (score 3):

The AWS CLI uses [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) to access elements of the output:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text
```

This will extract the `Account` value from the returned dictionary and output it in plain text.

JMESPath is extremely powerful. I highly recommend looking at the [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html).